# Extract coords from an image map to a csv file in order to store the coords in my database

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I have an html image map:

```
<img src="images\VA_cimetiere_recadrage.jpg" usemap="#Map" class="map" width="1300" height="785">
                    <map name="Map">
                        <area shape="rect" coords="124,680,149,746" href="#">
                        <area shape="rect" coords="98,680,123,746" href="#">
                        <area shape="rect" coords="70,680,95,746" href="#">
                        <area shape="rect" coords="1193,621,1259,642" href="#">
                        <area shape="rect" coords="1193,594,1259,615" href="#">
                        <area shape="rect" coords="338,31,359,93" href="#">
                        <area shape="rect" coords="317,31,338,93" href="#">
                        <area shape="rect" coords="126,35,152,98" href="#">
```

I want to store all my coords (307 coords) in my database, and I thought I could extract a csv file from all my coords generated in php so I don't have to enter them manually to the database, I wanted to know if it is possible and how can I do that ? I have done some research and found the "fgetcsv" function but I'm not sure if this is what I need
Thank you

Comment: I don’t see any particular use for `fgetcsv` here. You _could_ use that on `124,680,149,746` to get the individual numbers - but since it is _only_ numbers, and never anything that would come with any kind of “escaping of special characters”, a simple `explode` would do here as well. The slightly more challenging part is probably to get those number string out of the HTML in the first place. That would be a use case for  either regular expressions, or a DOM parser.

Comment: @CBroe Thank you but I have found a solution by doing a console.log() everytime I hover an area and then I just did a copy/past into my file ^^